# use absolute imports in react native project without typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, babeljs

How can i set absolute imports in react native project which is not using typescript. I watched many tutorials but they all talking about tsconfig.json, others are not working, that's what i tried in babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      [
        'module-resolver',
        {
          alias: {
            'src': './src',
          },
        },
      ],
    ],
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling upon this, I have working absolute paths in my React Native project without Typescript and it is due to my `babelrc` file. It looks like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["."]
    }]
  ]
}
```

`metro-react-native-babel-preset` an `babel-plugin-module-resolver`(aka "module-resolver") are dependencies you must install. I believe `metro-react-native-babel-preset` might ship with React Native already so you might not need it, but I have it in my project.

`babelrc` is similar to `bable.config.js` and what I've done here can most likely be converted to that format if you need that specific file type.

`root` tells babel where to start from, in this case, with the `"."`, we are starting literally from the root of my project, so my absolute paths start from there, but you can change this if you want to start from a different folder.

Hope this helps someone!